# read plist files in non-XML format using python

Tags: python, plist

I am reading MacOS data that is in plist (propertly list) format that is not in the XML format, not in the binary format, but in the other ascii format. For example:

```
addr= {
    City = "San Francisco Bay Area";
}
```

I am trying to parse this into a Python dictionary. Unfortunately, `plistlib.loads` returns `InvalidFileException()` when I try to parse it:

```
import plistlib

plist=b"""
addr= {
    City = "San Francisco Bay Area";
}
"""

print( plistlib.loads( plist ) )
```

Produces:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.py", line 9, in <module>
    print( plistlib.loads( plist ) )
  File "/Users/simsong/anaconda/lib/python3.6/plistlib.py", line 1024, in loads
    fp, fmt=fmt, use_builtin_types=use_builtin_types, dict_type=dict_type)
  File "/Users/simsong/anaconda/lib/python3.6/plistlib.py", line 1009, in load
    raise InvalidFileException()
plistlib.InvalidFileException: Invalid file
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Where have you seen in the doc that plistlib would support the plain text format ? "This module provides an interface for reading and writing the “property list” files used mainly by Mac OS X **and supports both binary and XML plist files.**"

Comment: Also I don't know what is this "other  ascii format" you're talking about, can't find any mention of it in the Plist man page.

Comment: Well, the "other ascii format" is the one that appears in my question. It doesn't need to be read with the `plistlib` module.

Comment: The (implied) question was "where does this 'other ascii format' come from and where is it documented" - because there's no mention of it in `plistlib` doc (https://docs.python.org/3/library/plistlib.html) nor in apple's plist man page (linked from the plistlib doc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about plist files in the JSON format. Your example is not JSON.

Let's start with this [sample plist in XML](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/UnderstandXMLPlist/UnderstandXMLPlist.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist SYSTEM "file://localhost/System/Library/DTDs/PropertyList.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Author</key>
    <string>William Shakespeare</string>
    <key>Lines</key>
    <array>
        <string>It is a tale told by an idiot,</string>
        <string>Full of sound and fury, signifying nothing.</string>
    </array>
    <key>Birthdate</key>
    <integer>1564</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And convert it to JSON format:

```
plutil -convert json sample.plist 

{"Author":"William Shakespeare","Birthdate":1564,"Lines":["It is a tale told by an idiot,","Full of sound and fury, signifying nothing."]}
```

Now you can read this using the JSON library.

```
import json

plist_text = '{"Author":"William Shakespeare","Birthdate":1564,"Lines":["It is a tale told by an idiot,","Full of sound and fury, signifying nothing."]}'

plist = json.loads(plist_text)

print('The author is ' + plist['Author'])
```

Output:

```
$ python3 plist.py 
$ The author is William Shakespeare
```

Comment: If it's not the binary or the XML format, then it *is* JSON -- that's the only other plist format.

Comment: I too have a .plist file I got from an app containing my RSS feeds because that app has stopped working it too can not be loaded by plistlib but I got your sample to work and the ending and beginning tags are fine something between line 1 and 7702 of the file is giving this library grief, I may be switching to JSON or XML real soon now...

Comment: You can scan a plist file to see if it OK plutil feeds.plist
feeds.plist: OK but the file in question can't be loaded by the library in question

Comment: Who knew this was so hard I get plutil -convert json feeds.plist 
feeds.plist: invalid object in plist for destination format

Comment: So the problem was some of the feeds at a last access date that evaluated to zero , ValueError: year 0 is out of range so removing those by hand in BBEdit finally lets me load the file in question into Python